# Rest-Framework: Serialize model with relationship to same model

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

I have a `Tag` model (as follows) that is capable of having a parent Tag (ie tag Django has a parent tag of Python) that I need to be serialized in my `TagSerializer` with the parent tag serialized.

```py
class Tag(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    aliases = ArrayField(
        models.CharField(max_length=50),
        size=8,
    )

    parent = models.ForeignKey(to="self", null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        db_table = "tags"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Notice I have the `parent` field which is a **ForeignKey** to another tag object.

In my serializer if I add the field `parent` to fields I get the following `ImproperlyConfigured` error.

```
Could not resolve URL for hyperlinked relationship using view name "tag-detail". You may have failed to include the related model in your API, or incorrectly configured the `lookup_field` attribute on this field.
```

```py
class TagSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Tag
        fields = ["name", "aliases", "parent"]

        extra_kwargs = {"aliases": {"validators": []}}
```

What I initially thought was I could add the `TagSerializer` for the `parent` attribute, but at this time it wouldn't be defined. So how would I serialize the parent tag?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by creating a `ParentTagSerializer` that uses the original `TagSerializer`.

```py
class ParentTagSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def to_representation(self, value):
        serializer_data = TagSerializer(value).data
        return serializer_data

    class Meta:
        model = Tag
        fields = "__all__"


class TagSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    parent = ParentTagSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = Tag
        fields = ["name", "aliases", "parent"]

        extra_kwargs = {"aliases": {"validators": []}}
```